# MySQL Events 'Update on Column'

Tags: mysql, sql, events

I have a table named "memo" and this is the structure:

```
+-------+-------------+-----------------------+--------+-------------------+
|   id  |   memo      |   date                | status |  valid until      |
+-------+-------------+-----------------------+----------------------------+
|   1   |   title1    | 2013-01-19 03:14:07   |   0    |  2013-01-19       |
|   2   |   title2    | 2013-01-19 04:14:07   |   0    |  2013-01-20       |
|   3   |   title3    | 2013-01-19 05:14:07   |   0    |  2013-01-23       |
|   4   |   title4    | 2013-01-19 06:14:07   |   1    |  2013-01-25       |
|   5   |   title5    | 2013-01-19 07:14:07   |   1    |  2013-01-27       |
+-------+-------------+-----------------------+--------+-------------------+
```

My concern here is that when a memo has met the due date (i.e. valid until) the status should change to 0.
How can I do this in MySQL Trigger? 
Any ideas would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an `event` for achieving this task. Trigger wont help since they are associated with entire row and gets executed on insertion, deletion or updation. 
Write a scheduled event which will execute say every hour (the frequency of running this is upto you) and check if the memo is valid or not. If it has expired make the corresponding `status` entry as 1.

Here is something to start with
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html

```
 CREATE EVENT myevent ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
  DO
    UPDATE memo SET status = 1 where sysdate()> valid until;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying my concern!
Now I can start this effectively.

Comment: Check out the edit! I have added sample code for you to start off.